# Creating a WPF Window that allows zooming and panning

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to create a Window that will hold several controls. However, I would like the user to be able to pan around and zoom in and out to see larger versions of those controls.

I don't even know where to begin looking.

I was going to start at ScaleTransform that responds to the use of the scroll button on the mouse but I am not sure if that is the best idea.

Just need a push in the right direction.

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be a good candidate for a `Viewbox`.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, you can Wrap the entire contents of the Window into a `Viewbox` like so:

```
<Window>
   <Viewbox>
       <!-- content here -->
   </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

and then bind to the `Viewbox` control's width and height to simulate the zooming. For a quick test, you could just listen to scroll wheel events via code-behind, name the Viewbox control, and access the Viewbox directly at change the values there.

**Edit**: here's a scenario I just found to get you started. They are using an image, but it's the exact same concept that I described above.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/working-with-wpf-viewbox-control/

Edit2: Quick working example using mouse-scroll

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        MouseWheel="MainWindow_OnMouseWheel">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox x:Name="ZoomViewbox" Stretch="Fill">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ZoomViewbox.Width = 100;
            ZoomViewbox.Height = 100;
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateViewBox((e.Delta > 0) ? 5 : -5);
        }

        private void UpdateViewBox(int newValue)
        {
            if ((ZoomViewbox.Width >= 0) && ZoomViewbox.Height >= 0)
            {
                ZoomViewbox.Width += newValue;
                ZoomViewbox.Height += newValue;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this viewbox respond to the middle mouse button events or is that something I have to build in?

Comment: That's something you'll have to build in. You'll set those events for the entire Window (not the Viewbox), and then when those events happen, you modify the Viewbox properties. Are you talking about just the scroll events of a mouse?

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how to accept more than one answer.

Comment: So this works great for zooming in and out. How would I tie in the "panning" part of it? The Click and Hold of the scroll wheel to drag around in the window?

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do the panning. Without panning, zooming is not of much use

Answer (score 14):

You can get functionality out of a ScrollViewer and a ScaleTransform. Here's an example:

```
<Window x:Class="CSharpWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- This ScrollViewer enables the panning -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <!-- This StackPanel is the container for the zoomable/pannable content. -->
            <!-- Any container control (StackPanel, DockPanel, Grid, etc) may be used here. -->
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <!-- This ScaleTransform implements the zooming and is bound the Value of the ZoomSlider -->
                <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" />
                </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>

                <!-- Here is your custom content -->
                <Button>Foo</Button>
                <Button>Bar</Button>

            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- This Slider controls the zoom level -->
        <Slider x:Name="ZoomSlider" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="8.0" LargeChange="0.25" SmallChange="0.01"  Value="1.0" />

    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found without code behind. Very elegant solution. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution :

```
    private void Window_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
            return;

        if (e.Delta < 0 && _scale > 0.7)
        {
            _scale -= 0.1;
            MainGrid.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(_scale, _scale);
        }               
        else if (e.Delta > 0 && _scale < 1.5)
        {
            _scale += 0.1;
            MainGrid.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(_scale, _scale);
        }
            
    }
```