# WPF Zoom control

Tags: wpf, zooming

How to implement zooming in wpf? Creating an application in which user can upload and draw on the map.On using zoom slider, user is not able to draw on the map. Without zoom slider the user is able to draw. Instead of third party controls, is there any way to implement zooming? I tried implementing it and i can see the slider in xaml but when i run it,the slider disappears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8a9d.png)
Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
     <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="273.333"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1026.667"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Slider x:Name="uiScaleSlider" ToolTip="Determines the UI scale factor." Value="1" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="4" Margin="67,0,-67,-0.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,0,0,-0.333">
                                    <DockPanel.LayoutTransform>

                                        <ScaleTransform 
        CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
        ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
    />
                                    </DockPanel.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Canvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" Margin="0,10,85,33">
                                        <Canvas.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/canvas.png" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                        </Canvas.Background>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ResizeDirection="Rows" />

                    </Grid>
```

Comment: 'user is not able to draw on the map' -- your code snippet doesn't give any evidence of how you're allowing the user to draw on the image.  If you remove the slider altogether from your sample then they still can't 'draw' on the image.

Comment: I know you told you don't want to use third party tools, but why create something again while it's already existing ? WPF Extensions give you a zoom control.
https://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a `ViewBox`. I've described a similar scenario here: [Creating a WPF Window that allows zooming and panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489400/creating-a-wpf-window-that-allows-zooming-and-panning/22489485#22489485)