# zoom in zoom out using wpf windows application window using Ctrl +Scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml

commands to move in the page horizontally by using: Ctrl + mouse scroll wheel
using WPF windows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SiuU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SiuU.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a ViewBox, similar to the scenario shown here: [Creating a WPF Window that allows zooming and panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489400/creating-a-wpf-window-that-allows-zooming-and-panning/22489485#22489485)

And you can use this code for mouse wheel control:

In constructor add event to PreviewMouseWheel

```
PreviewMouseWheel += Window_PreviewMouseWheel;
```

And then in the handler detect the key

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
        return;

    if (e.Delta > 0)
        ZoomIn();

    else if (e.Delta < 0)
        ZoomOut();
}
```