# Adding a zoom functionality to an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl that looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsPanel" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SquaresList}" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type logic:PFSquare}">
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}"
                       Height="{Binding Height}" 
                       Fill="{Binding Fill, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       Margin="{Binding Margin}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnMouseEnterCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnMouseDownCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnMouseRightCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It is just a grid of rectangles that looks like this:
[image: The Grid]
(the ItemsSource is an Observable Collection of 53^2 custom square class instances)

I have a set of events that when I click on certain squares changes the fill of the clicked square, it's important to note that I **need** those events to work correctly.
What I want is to be able to zoom in with my scroll wheel, I've tried implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489485/12342592) from another question however it completely destroyed the scale and ruined my items control. Is there a way to implement a zoom to this control and still retain both scale and the events?

Comment: I was up against a similar task and I ended up finding a control that worked pretty well and was not very expensive. https://www.ab4d.com/ZoomPanel.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an implementation of a pan and zoom panel, it provides everything that I needed. The implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/PanAndZoom)
It's important to note that it's not an actual panel, it's a control that you wrap around your content.