# Usercontrol isn't displaying its content

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

While I was trying to experiment with User Controls, I've stumbled upon this weird issue, which for some reason when I add the User Control to a Window, It just displays the border that I made, while not showing any content inside of it (whether I placed it within a border or a grid)

This is how it looks in the designer:

[image: User Control Designer]

And this is how it looks in a Window (in designer and on runtime):

[image: Window Designer]

As seen, It's not displaying the button nor the label.

User Control:

```xml
    <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FAF9F9" CornerRadius="20" Background="#FAF9F9">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.3" ShadowDepth="2" Direction="270"/>
            </Border.Effect>
            <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="428" FontSize="25"/>
                <Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" Height="47" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <Button.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.3" ShadowDepth="2" Direction="270"/>
                    </Button.Effect>
                    <Button.Template >
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                            <Grid >
                                <Path Stretch="Uniform" UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FFEA1E27">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                </Path>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like actual size of your control is smaller then design size. Thus, the label and the button are outside of Control's visible part.

Try positioning of `Label` and `Button` relative to bottom right and left corners instead of top-left.

```xml
<Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="47" Width="428" FontSize="25"/>
<Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="47" Height="47" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
```

Comment: This resolved the issue! Now I'm wondering if there's a way to make it responsive to resizing, like changing the font size of the label according to the width and height of the usercontrol in a window

Comment: @dotalw maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489400/creating-a-wpf-window-that-allows-zooming-and-panning/22489485#22489485) may help.